# How to build an array from an array of arrays

Tags: objective-c, ios, multidimensional-array

I am fairly new to iOS development.

I have a viewController that contains a property that is an object of a custom class.  We'll call that custom class ClassA. The object of ClassA has a property that is an NSMutableArray of objects of another custom class we'll call ClassB. ClassB has a property that is also an NSMutableArray of objects of type CLLocation.

From inside a method in the viewController I need to create a C array of CLLocationCoordinate2D structs (CLLocationCoordinate2D is a property of CLLocation). Each of these CLLocationCoordinate2D's needs to come from all of the CLLocation objects held by all of the objects in ClassB and ClassA. If I'm understanding what I've wrought, I believe I have a 3-D array.

I'm stuck on exactly how to go about assembling this array of structs. If it were just one array I would do something like this:

```
NSUInteger numberOfSteps = [objectOfClassX count];    
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[numberOfSteps];

for (NSInteger index = 0; index < numberOfSteps; index++) {
    CLLocation *location = [objectOfClassX objectAtIndex:index];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;

    coordinates[index] = coordinate;
}
```

However I'm struggling with the syntax of getting each object in the first array, then inside that each object in the second array, then inside that the CLLocationCoordinate2D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate once to get the total count of coordinates, then iterate again to copy them into a newly-allocated array.

```
NSInteger coordCount = 0, coordIndex = 0;
for(ClassA *a in collectionOfA)
    for(ClassB *b in a.collectionOfB)
        coordCount += [b.locations count];

CLLocationCoordinate2D coords[coordCount];

for(ClassA *a in collectionOfA)
  for(ClassB *b in a.collectionOfB)
    for(CLLocation *location in b.locations)
        coords[coordIndex++] = location.coordinate;
```

Comment: Note that if you want to actually store the array in an ivar, or somewhere else, you'll need to use `CLLocationCoordinate2D *coords = malloc(coordCount * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D))` instead, and manually `free` the memory later, since the array shown above is allocated on the stack and will go away if its containing scope ends.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! And thanks too for the array persistence tip - I wouldn't have caught that.

Answer (score -1):

just have a try : `coordinates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: objectOfClassX];`